# Does this photo show large crowds of protestors in Mexico?

Tags: politics, mexico

I'm prompted to ask this question by a [Facebook post by "US Uncut"](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=443357255698761).

**[Image lost to link rot.]**

> The Mexican media has blacking out the protests against their new government, who have been accused of doing everything from buying votes to buying off the media.
>
> If the corporate media won't spread this story, then let's spread the story. Share this all over your pages and your friend's pages and help support the democracy movement in Mexico.

It has a number of similarities to the [fake image of Occupy Wall Street protests](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6498/is-this-photo-of-occupy-wall-street-authentic) - improbably dense crowd, dodgy quality, and an indictment of the "corporate media" suppressing the truth. Also making me suspicious is how the same photo has popped up on a number of other websites, all without attribution, all with the same general message.

Comment: This picture is from campaign closure of Andres M. Lopez Obrador the leftist candidate, in which he and his party rallied what is presumed to be around 1.8 M people in the central plaza of Mexico City, a common rally point for all classes of manifestations. Anti government and anti electoral imposition protests seem to be less crowded than this one but indeed real, and had been spreading into mayor cities around the country. The news coverage have been scarce and censored by the 2 mexican media giants and pro government media sources. Still the "movement" hasn't really grown that much.

Comment: And about corporate media suppressing the truth, yes they are doing that, I've updated my answer

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, even with silly things as a soccer team winning X thing, people go to the streets _in mass_ to celebrate. source: I live in Mexico

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer: Yes, it is real**

I live in Mexico City, and those protests were real, the picture from the Facebook post by "US Uncut" looks real, but recently we have had many demonstrations like that, I think the date of that specific picture is June 27th, here are other pictures of the same day: 
[image: Picture 1]
source: http://lopezobradordvds.blogspot.mx/2012/06/amlo-cierre-de-campana-zocalo-de-la.html

[image: Picture 2]
source: http://lopezobrador.org.mx/2012/06/27/fotos-amlo-cierre-de-campana-en-el-zocalo-de-la-ciudad-de-mexico/mitin-amlo-zocalo-27-jun-12-9/

[image: Picture 3]
source: http://aristeguinoticias.com/zocalo-del-df-a-la-espera-de-amlo/

Here are the key words I used for the search:
[Junio+27+amlo+zocalo](http://www.google.com/imghp?tab=wi&q=Junio%2027%20amlo%20zocalo)

**UPDATE:**

[image]

This picture from the [Anarcho Queer blog](http://anarcho-queer.tumblr.com/post/27082215694) from @Daniel Carlsson answer is a different one from the original question, @Daniel Carlsson's picture indeed looks fake. Look at my first picture and you will see that it's almost the same point of view from the original picture. It is a mistake saying that a 2nd fake picture makes the 1st one fake.

**UPDATE 2:**

And about corporate media suppressing the truth, yes that is also true, the biggest media company in the Spanish speaking world received payments to give biased coverage to the elections:

[Computer files link TV dirty tricks to favourite for Mexico presidency](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/jun/07/mexico-presidency-tv-dirty-tricks)

[Mexico's Televisa files: how do we know they are genuine?](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/jun/08/mexico-televisa-files-genuine-qanda)

[Televisa should apologise to Mexicans for its Peña Nieto election bias](http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2012/jun/12/televisa-mexicans-tv-bias-pena-nieto)

Comment: How do you respond to the claims in the original answer to this questiont hat contradicts your answer? Also, please link to the sources of the photographs you selected, so we can check for ourselves.

Comment: @Oddthinking Done :)

Comment: anecdotal reference: yes they are real, I live in Mexico as well.

Comment: I'm convinced. The Aristegui blog has very sharp photos taken from various angles, and there are a number of details that are consistent among them (especially the positions of banners relative to one another).

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer: No**

The Facebook comments have a link to [Anarcho-Queer](http://anarcho-queer.tumblr.com/post/27082215694) that demonstrates this picture is photoshopped, using crowds in Montreal as the base photo.

[image]

But the [Mexicans really are  protesting](http://latino.foxnews.com/latino/lifestyle/2012/07/10/mexicans-loudly-protest-election-results-mass-media-quiet/).

Comment: I tend to believe the article you linked to by Tracy López on the Fox News Latino blog. However, I'm not satisfied with the fake-photo analysis by the Anarcho-Queer blog. I don't mean that I dispute the analysis; [it's just not the same photo](http://i.imgur.com/FdcAm.jpg) that US Uncut posted on Facebook.

Comment: I think @L2G is right. Anarcho-Queer has shown *another* photo is fake. But doesn't comment on *this* photo. Makes the conspiracy theorist wonder if an image was deliberately doctored just to act as a strawman.